# how to parse this url?

Tags: php

if I have this url: `node/95/pdf/1`. How will I able to get the numeric/value 1? Tried the parse_url but gave me the wrong output.

PS: the value 1 is just an example, the id is dynamic depends on what the user click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use  [sscanf](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php)

Untested example:

```
list($node_id, $pdf_id) = sscanf($url, "node/%d/pdf/%d");
```

`$node_id` contains the node id, `$pdf_id` contains the pdf id. According to your comment: Yes, you can output it with e.g. `echo $pdf_id;`.

If you need them both in an array, you can remove the `list()` method, doing it like this:

`$ids = sscanf($url, "node/%d/pdf/%d");`.

This returns an array with both node and pdf id in `$ids`.

Finally, if you just need the pdf id, you could do

`$id = sscanf($url, "node/95/pdf/%d");`.

I just showed how to fetch both because I assumed you may need both numbers from your url.

**Edit**
seeing all the other answers after posting my solution, I am wondering why everyone is solving this with multiple functions when there is a function available that does exactly what he needs: parsing a string according to a format. This also leads to less sql-injection prone code IMHO. And it doesn't break something when the url gets extended or query strings are appended.

**Edit 2**
`list($node_id, $sub, $sub_id) = sscanf($url, "node/%d/%[^/]/%d");` will get you the "pdf" and it's id separate instead of "node/%d/%s/%d". This is because char `/` is also matched by `%s`. Using `%[^/]` matches everything except the forward slash.

Comment: i don't quite get your code. How will get the pdf_id? echo $pdf_id? Sorry if i'm really slow on this.

Comment: in this example, sscanf returns an array. `%d` means "digits". so sscanf takes your url, and assumes there is `node/<any_digits>/pdf/<any_digits>`. the digits parts returned by sscanf as array. using list() saves them in separate variables, which could be convenient and because I thought you may also need the node id. I updated the answer to provide more examples.

Comment: tried your code but it return me a blank. var_dump($pdf_id) give me null. T_T. am i doing it wrong?

Comment: tried all your method but still return me a null value... hmmm.

Comment: You may need to read the sscanf page from the `php.net` manual. What does your url string look like? sscanf starts comparing from the beginning of your string. So if your `$url` looks like "domain.com/node/95/pdf/1" you need to adapt sscanf.

Comment: my url just looks like this: node/95/pdf/1.

Comment: ok, sorry, user error ^_^. i also want to get the string pdf. can list do this? tried using %s and return me this: pdf/1 but i just want to get the pdf.

Comment: `list($node_id, $sub, $sub_id) = sscanf($url, "node/%d/%[^/]/%d");` will get you the string and its id separated (in `$sub` and `$sub_id`).

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
$id = end(explode('/', 'node/95/pdf/1'));
```

**Example:**

```
$arr = explode('/', 'node/95/pdf/1');
$id = end($arr);
echo $id;  // 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$url = "node/95/pdf/1";
// Find the last occurence of a slash, get everything after that.
$id = substr($url, strrpos($url, "/") + 1 );
```

Comment: what if the id is in 100 or 1000? like node/95/pdf/1000.. would your code still be work?

Comment: @user1074776: As i said in the comment there, it gets everything after the last slash. The length of it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$input  = 'node/95/pdf/1';
$parts  = explode('/', $input);
$output = (int) $parts[3];
```